# Precalculating AES output length

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, rijndael

I am building a file transfer protocol that runs over TCP. I am encrypting data before sending it. Is it possible to calculate the size of the ciphertext before actually encrypting?

I want to send the filesize to the client so he knows when the datastream has ended, while pushing the ciphertext to the stream as soon as it is output.

To encrypt I am using the RijndaelManaged .NET class.

For example, a file of size 634 bytes is encrypting to 660 bytes.

Using the formula I found, and a block size of 16:

(inputSize / blockSize + 1) * blockSize

I am getting 650 bytes. Why is there the discrepancy?

Examples of input - output size pairs (in bytes):

Input: **905296** Output: **905332**

Input: **82320**  Output: **82356**

Input: **308**    Output: **340**

Answer (score 1):

The formula you found is not completely correct.
Given ECB or CBC (the only choices in this class):
Calculate (Bytecount / Blocksize) and **omit the decimal part**
Then add 1 for padding, then multiply with Blocksize.

634/16 = 39.625 => 40
40 * 16 = 640

The 10 other bytes...probably a header or something like that.
MS is known to add own stuff everywhere.

Comment: Using ceil(fileSize/16) * 16: A file of size 2014 bytes should encrypt to 2016 bytes, however I am getting 2036, this time a discrepancy of 20 bytes.

Comment: Using a larger file, size 905296 bytes, the ciphertext should be the same 905296, however I am getting 905332 bytes, 36 bytes different. I cannot see a pattern here, apart than the larger the data is, the bigger the discrepancy.